# Exclude post category from blog page but keep on posts page in WordPress default view

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I wanted to exclude the category `ID 1396` from displaying on the main blog post.

I added the following code to the child's `function.php` file:

```
function exclude_category($query) {
if ( $query->is_home() ) {
$query->set('cat', '-1396');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

This worked great and has stopped the category from appearing on the blog page.

Unfortunately, the blog posts with that category now disappear from the posts page in the WordPress backend, so they can't be edited in the new Default WordPress view. They can be viewed by changing to the classic wp-admin interface, but the client doesn't want to do that.

Is there a way to amend the code so I can see the posts in both views to edit them?

Comment: That might be conflict of blog page to homepage. Can you make sure going to WP Admin > Settings > Reading. And see the selection of Static homepage. If it is selected to "Show Latest Posts" , then you should use static page and then the above code should work to remove the category from homepage while let it stay on posts page.

Comment: Or maybe try replacing  `$query->is_home()` with `$query->is_front_page()` . Let me know in both cases please.

Comment: you can make the check `!is_admin()` which checks if you are currently in the backend or frontend.

Comment: so `if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() ) {`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The static homepage is set to 'Show Latest Posts'. When changing '$query->is_home()' to '$query->is_front_page()' I could see the posts to edit them in the WordPress backend, but they also appeared on the blog page, which we don't want.

Comment: @Stender Adding `!is_admin()` didn't work for me. In all cases, WordPress includes the posts in its count at the top, it just won't display the posts in that category. If you search for them, they can be found too...